# When I try to extract the date from string arose this message

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need a help again. I wanna extract the date from a string which I have pulled from pages. I use this video in order to do this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4avBXbNOGc&t=276s but when I use approximately the same code
[image: DataFrame]

```
index_Text_1 = df.columns.get_loc('Text_1')
index_Date = df.columns.get_loc('Date')
print(index_Text_1,index_Date)
pattern = r'\d{4}'
for row in range(0, len(df)):
    try:
        date = re.search(pattern, df.iat[row, index_Text_1]).group()
        df.iat[row, index_Date] = date
    except AttributeError:
        df.iat[row, index_Date] = " "
```

I got this:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-6c659860fe44> in <module>
      1 for row in range(0, len(df)):
      2     try:
----> 3         date = re.search(pattern, df.iat[row, index_Text_1]).group()
      4         df.iat[row, index_Date] = date
      5     except AttributeError:

~\Anaconda3\lib\re.py in search(pattern, string, flags)
    181     """Scan through string looking for a match to the pattern, returning
    182     a Match object, or None if no match was found."""
--> 183     return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
    184 
    185 def sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Could it be the `NaN` in the first row, which is passed to `re.search` but is neither a bytes-like object nor a string?

Comment: @David Wierichs if I make this code 'df.isnull().sum()' I got 'Text_1          1040'

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand how that addresses my point. That just shows that there are 1040 rows with NaN's in the column `Text_1`, right?

Comment: Yes, right. I am sorry that I didn't understand you

Comment: No worries! Did you resolve the issue? You could just include the TypeError in the `except` clause that you have anyways.

Comment: Jesus Christ! Done! The solution was on the floor. Thanks a lot!